# output of json and filter with ajax in zend framework to Make DataTables working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to implement jQuery DataTables into Zend Framework 1. I set up The following action in the controller:

```
public function getlistusersajaxAction()
{
    $users = new Admin_Model_DbTable_User();
    $param = $this->_request->getParam('filter','all');
    $userLoggin = $this->_sessionUser->getIdentity();$results = ($param === 'all') ? $users->fetchAll()->toArray() : $users->fetchAll($users->select()->where('rankUser = ?', $param))->toArray();$json=Zend_Json::encode($results);
    return $json;
```

and also in the index.phtml the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#table-user').dataTable({
            'info': false,
            'ajax': '/<?=Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Locale')->getLanguage();?>/admin/UserManagement/getlistusersajax/filter/',
            'sDom': 'lTfr<"clearfix">tip 
        });
```

The problem is that I have this error:

> DataTables warning: table id=table-user - Ajax error.

It shows as loading, but gives no output. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance

Comment: did you declared `table-user` in your html `table` id...?

Comment: yes `<table id="table-user" class="table table-hover">`thanks in advance

Comment: Ok fine.did you checked your `json` data columns and declare in your jquery `columns` to display data.

Comment: i am newbie on dataTables but i don't know very well so my code in below thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow some steps while returning `json_encode` data.

- Make sure you retrieved data and columns `count` should be equal.
- Make sure to declare `id` in your `table`

Sample example for return of your `database` results

```
$output = array(
            'sEcho' => intval($sEcho),
            'iTotalRecords' => $iTotal,
            'iTotalDisplayRecords' => $iFilteredTotal,
            'aaData' => array()
        );
```

And in Jquery need to declare `columns` to display data like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#table-user').dataTable({
           'ajax':'yoururl',
          // Some stuff
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mData": "columnname" },
            { "mData": "columnname" },
            ------ ]   
        }); });
```

If you are using `server-side` processing you can use `"sAjaxSource"` instead of `ajax`. It will also process the Request.For more details about datatable parameters check this [link](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side)

Here is the example of [server side processing](http://datatables.net/development/server-side/php_mysql) using PHP.

This is not my answer of your problem. This information help to you solve the problem.Thanks !

Comment: i am newbie on DataTables if you can give me the Example on my code Thanks in advance

Comment: I already given example link in my answer. Check it once http://datatables.net/development/server-side/php_mysql.

Comment: i see that but i am not on php simple i work on zend framework MVC,i need the things it's near to my code

Comment: Its simple also in Zend. First you need to get the data in correct format like i given `$output=array(...)`. after that you need to do `json_encode` and then declare `columns` in your `jquery`.  Nothing much complicated.Just follow the steps.You ll achieve!

Comment: i do that `<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#table-user').dataTable({
   'info': false,
   'ajax': '/<?=Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Locale')->getLanguage();?>/admin/UserManagement/getlistusersajax/filter/',
   'sDom': 'lTfr<"clearfix">tip'`but see error script 'user-management/getlistusersajax.phtml' not found in path i don't know how can i resolved that

Comment: what it means`/<?=Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Locale')->getLanguage();?>`.Is it you root path to call the `action`. I am scared of this line. what it will results..? Check your path

Comment: yes,so please can you tell me what can i do in my script to resolve this problem thanks in advance

Comment: we are not here to help you from scratch..You should learn the things. All the best!