# No matching records found dataTables on zend framework 1

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, zend-framework, datatables

i spent a lot of time on this problem I am using DataTable Jquery   into Zend Framework The following action in the controller:

```
public function getlistusersajaxAction()
{
    $users = new Admin_Model_DbTable_User();
    $param = $this->_request->getParam('filter','all'); 
    $results = ($param === 'all') ? $users->fetchAll()->toArray() : $users->fetchAll($users->select()->where('rankUser = ?', $param))->toArray();
    $results = array();
    $results = array(
                "iTotalRecords" => 34,
                "iTotalDisplayRecords" => 34,
                "aaData" => array()
        );

    $this->_helper->json->sendJson($results);
```

in the index.phtml the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#table-user').dataTable({
             "bProcessing": true,
             "bServerSide": true,
             "sAjaxSource": "/<?=Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Locale')->getLanguage();?>/admin/UserManagement/getlistusersajax/filter/"
```

I tried to find some guidance on the solution applied here but it didn't gave me success.

What could I be missing?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is same like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29647851/output-of-json-and-filter-with-ajax-in-zend-framework-to-make-datatables-working

Comment: `$results` returns `empty` array of values. Could you please show your `print_r($results)` data.